# Geting an error when executin the stored Procedure in my MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Hi all i have method where i pass some parameters to the stored procedure and when i execute it i get this error

**[The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.]**

this is how i am calling my storedprocedure

```
  public JsonResult CreatedBugs()
    {
        int year;
        int month;
        int projectid;
        year = 2012;
        month = 8;
        projectid = 16;
        var loggedbugs = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<LoggedBugs>("LoggedBugs @Year,@Month,@ProjectID", new SqlParameter("@Year",year ), new SqlParameter("@Month",  month ), new SqlParameter("@ProjectID", projectid )).ToList();
        var ClosedBugs = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<LoggedBugs>("ClosedBugs @Year,@Month,@ProjectID", new SqlParameter("@Year", year), new SqlParameter("@Month", month), new SqlParameter("@ProjectID", projectid)).ToList();
        var model = new LoggedBugs
        {
            LoggedBugsCount = loggedbugs,
            ClosedBugs = ClosedBugs
        };
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and this is my StoredProcedure

```
      alter procedure LoggedBugs
      (
      @Year int,
      @Month int,
      @ProjectID int
      )
      as
      begin
       SELECT projectName,
    ProjectYear,
    ProjectMonth, 
      Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4, Week5
          FROM (
 Select  p.projectName,YEAR(b.CreatedDate) ProjectYear, MONTH(b.CreatedDate) ProjectMonth,
        'Week' + CAST(DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, b.CreatedDate), 0), b.CreatedDate)+1 AS VARCHAR) as [Weeks],
        b.BUGID
From    BUGS b inner join projects p on b.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
Where   DatePart(year, CreatedDate) = @Year and datepart(month, Createddate) = @Month and b.projectid = @ProjectID 
  ) p
   PIVOT (COUNT(BUGID) FOR [Weeks] IN (WEEK1, WEEK2, WEEK3, Week4, Week5)) AS pvt
 end
```

where am i doing wrong here

**Edit1**

here is my LoggedBug Class

```
 public class LoggedBugs
{
    public string projectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectYear { get; set; }
    public string ProjectMonth { get; set; }
    public string Week1 { get; set; }
    public string Week2 { get; set; }
    public string Week3 { get; set; }
    public string Week4 { get; set; }
    public string Week5 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LoggedBugs> LoggedBugsCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LoggedBugs> ClosedBugs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for LoggedBugs class, and also what are the sql types for ProjectYear, ProjectMonth, Week1, Week2, Week4, Week4,Week5. My guess is that your proc is returning an int but LoggedBugs has it defined as a string type

Comment: @nuhusky2003 i had updated my question with the LoggedBug class and i am cast as varchar for the ProjectYear, ProjectMonth, Week1, Week2, Week4, Week4,Week5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be problem with `ProjectYear` and `ProjectMonth`. At database side they are `int`, so at .NET side they would propably unboxed as `System.Int32`. In your entity they are `string`. 
Try convert it to `varchar` in your sp or change types in entity to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ProjectYear and ProjectMonth properties to type int in LoggedBugs class. Your sql returns them as int, see [YEAR SQL MSDN description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) since YEAR and MONTH sql functions both return values of type int. Your C# code expects a string, so you get a type mismatch exception.